# Is "ho-hooo" familiar as an owl sound?

Tags: ambiguity

I am writing an article and I am wondering if the readers will understand that **hoo-hooo** is an owl sound.
It's for an American audience.

The article starts like this

> Everything was silent except for the occasional *moo* or *ho-hoooo*

Will the readers understand that I am talking about owls? 
Should I just one sound instead of two?

Comment: Maybe “who-hooo.” (I would pronounce “ho- hooo” as rhyming with    “go who” and that’s not the stereotypical sound of an owl.)

Comment: I wouldn't put "ho" in it, unless it's a Santa Claus owl. You want at least "hoo". Ho ho ho!

Comment: "I am writing an article". If it's an article, I'd use more formal language, such as lowing and hooting. In a children's story, this would be OK, though "hoot hoot" might be better, or at least hoo-hoo. (Starting with ho- is a tad confusing, and conjures Christmasy associations.

Comment: Looks like we all had the same idea at about the same time...

Comment: They don't celebrate Christmas where I'm from so I totally missed the ho thing. Thanks !

Comment: I'd be most familiar with "hoooooooo" or "whooooooo" -- those I'd read as owl sounds without further elaboration.  "Ho-hoooo" is iffier, and "hoot hoot" sounds like a train or car horn.

Comment: And now we have a question about ho's and hooters and Christmas. (Not sure what it's owl about.)

Comment: @Drew - You're a hoot.

Answer (score 1):

"Hoot hoot" is more common, though I believe your sentence will be understood by the average English speaker.